# Azure DevOps API - Create new branch from master without adding changes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, branch, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm attempting to use Azure DevOps Services Rest API to create a new branch from master but I've been unsuccessful.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/update-refs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples

Endpoint: [https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/git/repositories/{{repositoryId}}/refs?api-version={{api-version}}](https://dev.azure.com/%7B%7Borganization%7D%7D/%7B%7Bproject%7D%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7B%7BrepositoryId%7D%7D/refs?api-version=%7B%7Bapi-version%7D%7D)

Body:

```
[
  {
    "name": "refs/heads/new-test-branch-from-api-call",
    "oldObjectId": "{{masterObjectId}}",
    "newObjectId": "{{newObjectId}}"
  }
]
```

Results:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF401035: The object '****************************************' does not exist.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitObjectDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server",
    "typeKey": "GitObjectDoesNotExistException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

A comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846426/azure-devops-rest-api-to-create-a-branch-from-a-specific-branch/59852211#59852211) post states that this is the route to take. Also states that the `repositoryId` should be used and the `newObjectId` which results in:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "An object ID must be 40 characters long and only have hex digits. Passed in object ID: ********-****-****-****-************.",
    "typeName": "System.ArgumentException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "ArgumentException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newObjectId` is the object id of the existing branch. Really not sure why this is named new when it is actually older. Very odd.

```
[
  {
    "name": "refs/heads/new-test-branch-from-api-call",
    "newObjectId": "{{BranchObjectIdGoesHere}}",
    "oldObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  }
]
```

Comment: Presumably they call it "new" because it's the new *value* that the corresponding *ref* needs to hold. That's also the Git terminology, though anything involving json data like this is outside Git.